# Separating spring tomcat executor threads based on API Path

Tags: java, spring, performance, tomcat, java-threads

We have a critical service which consist of many different APIs. Some of the APIs are more critical then other APIs. We can classify them in 2 different buckets, P0 APIs and P1 APIs.
The issue that I have observed is, when there is an issue with non critical P1 APIs, which leads to increase in latency of all those APIs. It also starts impacting the P0 APIs, we observe increase in number of Http 500. After some investigations, I figured it was because the tomcat executor thread are now more occupied on the P1 APIs as they are latent. This results in P0 APIs waiting more for a tomcat executor threads.

Now, We can solve this by increasing the tomcat executor thread count (server.tomcat.max-threads). But they will only be utilised when there is a increase in latency across other APIs, and in happy cases many of the threads would sit ideal.

Is there a way to configure the tomcat threads pool individually for each API path ?
For Eg:
For all API path having `/api/p0/*` path will have a different tomcat executor thread pool.
and for all API path having `/api/p1/*` path will have another different tomcat executor thread pool.

This will help with isolation and we can make sure that P1 Apis are not impacting P0 APIs. Please do let me know if you need more insights or my description is not enough to understand the problem statement. Will try my best to help you guys with any information needed.

I tried increasing the number of max threads server.tomcat.max-threads which mitigated the problem.

Although I am looking for a more optimal way which can help me with isolation of various different APIs.

Comment: Split them in different applications/services and deploy seperatly.